# how to execute Selenium IDE script in hudson with selenium rc

Tags: hudson

I have exported a recorded script in html and now trying to execute that script from hudson,but every time i am getting below mention message, please let me know what i am missing or where is my fault

```
11:58:08.851 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.1-b02
11:58:08.852 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 x86
11:58:08.859 INFO - v2.2.0, with Core v2.2.0. Built from revision 13073
11:58:08.972 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
11:58:08.973 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
11:58:08.974 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
11:58:08.974 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
11:58:08.975 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
11:58:08.995 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@186d4c1
11:58:08.995 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
11:58:08.998 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
11:58:08.998 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@18a47e0
11:58:09.155 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
11:58:12.410 INFO - Launching Firefox...
11:58:16.169 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
InterruptedException!
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: test_full #9 due to result: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tried to follow the suggested steps but it do not worked for me.still facing the same issue 
Please find the details of my test suit file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
  <title>Test Suite</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="suiteTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="selenium"><tbody>
<tr><td><b>Test Suite</b></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="tc1.html">tc1</a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am still getting the same error

Also would like to confirm one thing that i am using selenium IDE for test suite creation and I do not export the test suite file to HTML but simply save it with .html extension,I have compared both the file and found no changes

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely reason is that you are exporting and trying to run Test Case not Test Suite. Please check [this](http://www.oshyn.com/_blog/Software_Development/post/Selenium-Test-Suite/) page. Normally Test Suite is a html file that points to Test Case html files. Spent a few hours getting my head around this today and eventually got it working.

Here is an example of a Test Suite that contains Test Cases.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Suite Function Tests - Priority 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr><td><b>Suite Of Tests</b></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="./Login.html">Login</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="./SearchValues.html">Test Searching for Values</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="./SaveValues.html">Test Save</a></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

From [Selenium doc page](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#test-suites)

Comment: Also, I know that Selenium IDE generates extra line that begins with  "<xml .... " when you export to HTML try removing that.

Comment: already did that but there is some other problem, my test suite are not listed in the browser and there are no test cases when i run selenium rc

Comment: Can you show me the command line that you run to start selenium-RC test. Also your test case/suite files that you are using

Comment: java -jar c:\selenium-server-standalone-2.12.0.jar -htmlSuite firefox http://www.google.com "C:\Test\Test.html" "C:\Test\Testr.html", I am able to launch the firefox but there is no test suite listed or test case

Comment: test suite is not listed, and test case section is also blank when i execute the above command,it shows that "404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /selenium-server/tests/testsuite1.html?thisIsChrome=true&thisIsHTA=false was not found on this server. That’s all we know"

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
  <title>Test Suite</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="suiteTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="selenium"><tbody>
<tr><td><b>Test Suite</b></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="file:///C:\Users\Mitul_new\Desktop\Test suite\tc1.html">tc1</a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Could you show me whats inside "tc1.html" (use http://pastebin.com and paste URL here) And the user that you are launching RC server with has permissions to read  tc1.html? Also try this http://pastebin.com/18F3QE9u as your test suite and place your tc1.html into the same directory as test suite. Try using https://www.google.com on the command line when launching slenium-rc server.

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><link rel="selenium.base" href="http://www.google.co.in/" /><title>tc1</title></head><body><table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1"><thead><tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">tc1</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>open</td><td>/</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>type</td><td>id=lst-ib</td><td>test</td></tr><tr><td>click</td><td>name=btnG</td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>

Comment: please help i have pasted my test case html file too